# Django website toggling between latest and previous state on reload

Tags: django, apache

today, I have recognized a strange behaviour of my Apache served Django 2.0.2 (Webfaction) website. After I have made a change and restarted the Apache server, the reloaded website shows the latest change. But when I hit F5 (reload) again, the view of the previous state is displayed again. Another reload and the latest state is displayed. That continues back and forth. For example, see the smallcaps and line-break changes:
[image: top: current state, bottom: previous state, red: annotations]

Before, the same happened to the background opacity, too, so it's not limited to the font.

It happens on Firefax (PC) as well as on Opera and Chrome browsers (on mobile dev). So, I assume the issue lies in Apache - or Django. I've never seen such a behaviour, before. Does anyone have an idea what causes this effect?

Not sure whether it is of help (because the site will soon change), but for reproduction of the error, this is the site: http://campfire.skylet.de/

Thank you
Michael

Comment: The changes are coming from inline css style being applied to those elements: `font-feature-settings: 'smcp' 1;` but it's hard to say anything further than that. Definitely weird.

Comment: In fact, this and the <BR> in the sub-header were the latest uploaded change. Before that, I'd switched the dark overlay from 0.6 to 0.7 alpha and that brighter-darker-brighter on reload made me fully recognize this effect.